# How to shuffle result from query in Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

I get result of query and try shuffle this.
I tried to use `shuffle` in php, but it works only for arrays.

Also I can use `random()` in query, but it is slow

Answer (score 12, accepted):

see this pls 
[Laravel Collection method shuffle](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-shuffle)

Comment: Apparently it also allows a "seed" parameter, which is useful if you're using pagination and want to prevent duplicates on subsequent pages: https://github.com/illuminate/support/blob/5.6/Collection.php#L1380 (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37548548/470749)