# How to randomize results of ResourceCollection but still paginate api results

Tags: php, laravel

I have setup an API in Laravel that returns paginated results of Albums that are stored in my database. It currently returns 15 results with the rest paginated, however I want to randomize the results before paginating.
This is the code in my api.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Album;

Route::apiResource('/album', 'AlbumController');
```

This is the code for AlbumController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Album;
use App\Http\Resources\AlbumResource;
use App\Http\Resources\AlbumResourceCollection;

class AlbumController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Return AlbumResource which wraps all data in an object named data.
     *
     * @param Album $album
     * @return AlbumResource
     */
    public function show(Album $album): AlbumResource {
        return new AlbumResource($album);
    }

    public function index(): AlbumResourceCollection {
        return new AlbumResourceCollection(Album::paginate());
    }
}
```

I tried altering the index() function and I was able to randomize 15 results, however, I end up losing pagination. I did accomplished that with changing the function to this:

```
    public function index(): AlbumResourceCollection {
        return new AlbumResourceCollection(Album::all()->random(15));
    }
```

What I want is something along the lines of this:

1. Get all results
2. Randomize results
3. Paginate it

I also attempted this but I got an error:

```
    public function index(): AlbumResourceCollection {
        return new AlbumResourceCollection(Album::all()->random()->paginate());
    }
```

Any thoughts on what I can do to accomplish this?

Comment: Laravel Builtin pagination will not work for you. Even if you make custom paginator, you can get all results and randomize it. after that you can paginate the result. Main issue is that you can get same record in next pages of the pagination. May be caching or something else might do a trick

Comment: Here is the one way to achieve that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37546922/laravel-paginate-random-records but it will show random but same records for multiple users

Comment: Thanks for the comments Sagar. Is there a reason why built in pagination won't work for me?  I also attempted to use the code from that answer as well, however when I use the isRandomOrder function I get this error saying the function is not defined. Method Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Collection::inRandomOrder does not exist. I am on Laravel 6.5.1

Comment: May be that function is deprecated in the latest laravel. I can explain the reason, suppose you have data like 1,2,3,4,5,6 when you take in random order lets say you get 3,6 in first page. In second page, it will again randomize the records so you might get data like 4,6 in second page. so there is likely chance of duplicate records in next pages.

Comment: `inRandomOrder` isn't a Collection method, it is a Query Builder method

Comment: You have to try first part of the solution of the question i have linked

Comment: that answer linked is horribly formed ... they are calling query builder methods on collections, remove the `all()` method call from all those examples in it

Comment: Sagar, thanks for that explanation, that makes some sense. I can research maybe caching that pagination results for a few minutes or something. I tried the answer from the link, however I get the following answer error - Method Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Collection::orderBy does not exist.

Comment: Thank you so much lagbox! Removing the all() method was the solution for me!

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was as lagbox mentioned in the comments.
I updated my index function to the following:

```
    public function index(): AlbumResourceCollection {
        return new AlbumResourceCollection(Album::inRandomOrder(rand(0, 5000))->paginate());
    }
```